# How to differentiate the Activity sent by Adaptive Card Submit Action and User typed Text in MS Bot Framework V3?

Tags: botframework

I am integrating Bing Spell Check in my bot to auto correct the spell mistakes before sending it to **QnA Maker**.

I have also implemented an Adaptive Card Response with different buttons having some suggestions which user can try if Bot does not understand the utterance of the user.

Now the challenge is that user can click on the Adaptive Card Button from the suggestions list. In this case, I don't want Bing Spell Check to be hit because the sentences will ideally be correct.

I am using MS Web Chat control and Bot hosted on a web page. The problem is I am unable to differentiate between Action Submit and User Typed Text based on any property in the activity. I tried adding **DataJson** in the **AdaptiveSubmitAction** but when I do this the text of the button clicked is not displayed in the bot. With Data property, if the user clicks on a button it displays the text in the bot.

Please guide me and let me know if anyone needs more clarification regarding this question.

**Edit: Adding Sample Reproducible code.** The Adaptive Card Template to be returned by bot in response which contains some Action.Submit Buttons.

```
public static AdaptiveCard GetQuestionSuggestionsCard(List<string> Questions)
        {
            AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard()
            {
                Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                {
                    new AdaptiveContainer()
                    {
                        Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                        {
                            new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                            {
                                Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>()
                                {
                                    new AdaptiveColumn()
                                    {
                                        Width = "stretch",
                                        Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                        {
                                            new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                            {
                                                Text = string.Format("I am not sure what you are asking. \n\n I have {0} {1} that might help you find an answer.", Questions.Count, Questions.Count > 1 ? "suggestions" : "suggestion" ),
                                                Wrap = true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                // Buttons
                Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
            };
            foreach (string question in Questions)
            {
                card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction() { Title = question, Data = question });
            }
            //Add None choice if have suggestive questions
            if (Questions.Count > 0 && card.Actions.Count > 0)
            {
                card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction() { Title = AppSettings.NoneSuggestionChoiceText, Data = AppSettings.NoneSuggestionChoiceText });
            }
            return card;
        }
```

**The Adaptive Card Returned to the bot -**

```
private Activity DisplaySuggestions(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
        { 
if (lstDisplaySuggestionQuestions.Count > 0)
                        {
                            //create the reply
                            Activity reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply();
                            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                            // Create the attachment.
                            Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                            {
                                ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                                //take the max displayed suggestions configured from Config Key
                                Content = AdaptiveCardHelper.GetQuestionSuggestionsCard(lstDisplaySuggestionQuestions.Take(AppSettings.QnAMaxNumberOfDisplayedSuggestions).ToList())
                            };
                            reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                            return reply;
                        }
}
```

When user click on the Action Button it posts a text to bot which also is displayed as utterance in conversation. Now I want to uniquely identify if utterance is posted from text input box or from a Adaptive Card Button Click.

I hope, I will be making sense. To reproduce create a bot, add the card then type some text and check the Post method in Message Controller and look at the Activity object. Then do the same for Action Button Click and focus on the Text property.

Comment: Which sdk are you using? C# or nodejs? Can you also post the generic schema for your adaptive card?

Answer (score 0):

The v3 adaptive card sample bot has an example of sorting out submit actions within your bot after receiving a response from a card. Basically, a "submit" response will have a `value` field, while a normal message will not.

[For nodejs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/v3-sdk-samples/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards/app.js#L31):

```
if (session.message && session.message.value) {
    // A Card's Submit Action obj was received
    processSubmitAction(session, session.message.value);
    return;
}
```

[For C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/cards-AdaptiveCards/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs#L30):

```
if (message.Value != null)
    {
        // Got an Action Submit
        dynamic value = message.Value;
        string submitType = value.Type.ToString();
        ...
```

So in the case where this is false for your bot, you can send it to the spell checker.

Comment: HI Mark,  I have tried using the DataJson in the AdaptiveSubmitAction but the problem is I have a requirement when user clicks a button the title or say text of the button is displayed in the bot as conversation and then send to QnA Dialog to process. If I implement DataJson then it does not shows the text, if by any means I can get both text and custom JSON then would be great. But looking under the hood of AdaptiveSubmitAction.cs code this does not seems to be viable. https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/source/dotnet/Library/AdaptiveCards/AdaptiveSubmitAction.cs

Comment: Can you please update your question with a minimal reproducible sample? I don't think I understand what your specific problem is.

Comment: To note, `DataJson` doesn't really have anything to do with this answer for the issue of sorting out text entered in by the customer from responses entered via an `Action.Submit` within a card, can you please confirm if this solution doesn't work/fit what you meant by the question?

Comment: I have added some reproducible code to understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: Mark, were you able to replicate and understand the issue. Any suggestions are really welcome.